# What source package the Installation Wizard of Deepin OS is using?

Tags: linux, deepin

Lately Deepin Linux caught my attention and tried installing it for a test run.

The installation wizard is really interesting and very helpful for new linux users.

I'm wondering if I can implement it in another distribution remix which I am barely working.

[image: Deepin Linux Installation Wizard]

My question is what Installation wizard are they are using ? Is it available for me to use?

image: linux.com

Comment: English corrected. Please do take time in the future to write coherent posts.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry about that :) . and thank you.